# C# Webforms show Loading indicator during code execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

The Webforms application I have is very data heavy, it's mostly ASP controls doing ADO.net operations. I have loading times of anywhere from 5-15 seconds, which is normal, but I'd like to make it more obvious to the user that their request is being processed.

What I'd like to do is add a loading image or some kind of visual element that will show when server code runs.

ASP:

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="OKbutton" runat="server"
    Skin="WebBlue"
    Text="OK">
</telerik:RadButton>
```

C#:

```
private SqlDataReader dr = null;
protected void OKbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Long running query
    string query = "UPDATE Employees SET Salary = 12345 WHERE EmployeeID = 123"

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, db.DbConnection);

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: How is backend code called for execution? Full postback, AJAX call, Update Panel?

Comment: Are you using AJAX to process the long requests?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I have I think one of my controls doing a full postback.  The rest are Update Panels.

Comment: For UpdatePanel ones use UpdateProgress - it kicks in after set time and displays template you specify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use jquery BlockUI for this. Link to [Demo](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos). This should work for all your cases (full postback and partial postback).

Add event handlers for `beginRequest` and `endRequest` of [PageRequestManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311028(v=vs.100).aspx).
In the `BeginRequestHandler` you can start displaying the loading indicator with your customized settings and in the `EndRequestHandler` you hide the loading indicator. If you don't want to block the whole page then this plugin has option to show the loading indicator for an element (eg. within a div in the page, refer the demo page)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
        prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    }

    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        showLoadingUI();
    }

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        $.unblockUI();
    }

    function showLoadingUI() {
        $.blockUI({
            message: '<h3><img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" /> <br /> <span style="font-family: Tahoma,Verdana,Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size: 12px; color: #1390c6;"> Loading...</span></h3>',
            showOverlay: true,
            css: {
                width: '130px', height: '110px',
                border: 'none',
                padding: '10px',
                '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                opacity: .9
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Also remember to reference the jquery and the blockui plugin scripts from either CDN or from your local application.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with an animated image use pure code. Just display this whenever it is needed.

[spin.js](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/)